# How could I get multiple values from keys in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

How do I get a value from a dictionary without using a key?

I am making a periodic table code where you put in an input for the symbol and you get information on the element e.g if someone puts 'H' they will get information on Hydrogen.

But how do I get the information?

```
class Element:
    H, He, Li, Be, B, C, N, O, F, Ne, Na, Mg, Al, Si, P = list(range(1, 16))
    S, Cl, Ar, K, Ca, Sc, Ti, V, Cr, Mn, Fe, Co, Ni, Cu, Zn = list(range(16, 31))
    Ga, Ge, As, Se, Br, Kr, Rb, Sr, Y, Zr, Nb, Mo, Tc, Ru = list(range(31, 45))
    Rh, Pd, Ag, Cd, In, Sn, Sb, Te, I, Xe, Cs, Ba, La, Ce = list(range(45, 59))
    Pr, Nd, Pm, Sm, Eu, Gd, Tb, Dy, Ho, Er, Tm, Yb, Lu, Hf = list(range(59, 73))
    Ta, W, Re, Os, Ir, Pt, Au, Hg, Tl, Pb, Bi, Po, At, Rn = list(range(73, 87))
    Fr, Ra, Ac, Th, Pa, U, Np, Pu, Am, Cm, Bk, Cf, Es, Fm = list(range(87, 101))
    Md, No, Lr, Rf, Db, Sg, Bh, Hs, Mt, Ds, Rg, Cn, Uut = list(range(101, 114))
    Fl, Uup, Lv, Uus, Uuo = list(range(114, 119))


class Category:
    UNKNOWN               = 0
    DIATOMIC_NONMETAL     = 1
    ALKALI_METAL          = 2
    ALKALINE_EARTH_METAL  = 3
    TRANSITION_METAL      = 4
    LANTHANIDE            = 5
    ACTINIDE              = 6
    POST_TRANSITION_METAL = 7
    METALLOID             = 8
    NONMETAL              = 9
    NOBLE_GAS             = 10
    SYNTHETIC             = 11


class Phase:
    GAS = 0
    LIQUID = 1
    SOLID = 2


ELEMENTS_DATA = {
    Element.H: {
        "name": _("Hydrogen"),
        "atomic-mass": 1.0079,
        "boil": 20.271,
        "category": Category.NONMETAL,
        "density": 0.08988,
        "discovered-by": "Henry Cavendish",
        "melt": 13.99,
        "molar-heat": 28.836,
        "named-by": "Antoine Lavoisier",
        "number": 1,
        "period": 1,
        "phase": Phase.GAS,
        "source": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen",
        "summary": "Hydrogen is a chemical element with chemical symbol H and atomic number 1. With an atomic weight of 1.00794 u, hydrogen is the lightest element on the periodic table. Its monatomic form (H) is the most abundant chemical substance in the Universe, constituting roughly 75% of all baryonic mass.",
        "symbol": "H",
        "x": 1,
        "y": 1
    },
}

I also have removed most of the code as it would be too long.
```

Answer (score 0):

> *I am making a periodic table code where you put in an input for the symbol and you get information on the element **e.g if someone puts 'H' they will get information on Hydrogen**.*

So why did you make this at the beginning of the program...

```
H, He, Li, Be, B, C, N, O, F, Ne, Na, Mg, Al, Si, P = list(range(1, 16))
```

...instead of directly this?

```
ELEMENTS_DATA = {
    'H': {
        # All that other stuff
    }
}
```

This way you will be able to simply write this line:

```
print(ELEMENTS_DATA[input('> ').upper()])
```

So that when the user writes this:

```
> H
{
    "name": _("Hydrogen"),
    "atomic-mass": 1.0079,
    "boil": 20.271,
    "category": 9, # Category.NONMETAL,
    "density": 0.08988,
    "discovered-by": "Henry Cavendish",
    "melt": 13.99,
    "molar-heat": 28.836,
    "named-by": "Antoine Lavoisier",
    "number": 1,
    "period": 1,
    "phase": 0, # Phase.GAS,
    "source": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen",
    "summary": "Hydrogen is a chemical element with chemical symbol H and atomic number 1. With an atomic weight of 1.00794 u, hydrogen is the lightest element on the periodic table. Its monatomic form (H) is the most abundant chemical substance in the Universe, constituting roughly 75% of all baryonic mass.",
    "symbol": "H",
    "x": 1,
    "y": 1
}
```

They will get what expected.

Comment: I made the classes so if I put the input 1 it would return as Hydrogen and not Helium

Comment: What do you expect to get from input "H"?

Comment: Each one of the information under Element.H

Comment: In this case my solution should work.